# Looking to total cells, but leave some blank in between

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I've written a worksheet for selling work.  I have one column "C" for the cost, and the column next to it "D" for a subtotal.  Depending on the work to be performed, not all rows will have values to input.

It is easy enough to autosum them down the line, but I am looking for something a little more sophisticated.  Right now, when the cost cell is empty, the subtotal will repeat the total from the previous subtotal cell.  I want to subtotal column to pull the value from the cost cell directly left of it, but to also add the previous value from the subtotal cell directly above (even if there are blank cells in between) so that I have a running total down the subtotal column.  This is easily achieved if I total them for each individual job I create, but I am looking for a template that I can keep to use as a fresh start to each write up.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, I think, is this. Assuming that C1 and D1 are headers, and your first row of data is row 2, put this formula into D2, then drag/autofill the formula down to the bottom:

```
=IF($C2>0,SUM($C$2:$C2),0)
```

If there is a value in C5, then the value of D5 will be the sum of C2:C5. The same applies for C9, or whatever. In your final total cell, just use the sum of C:C (or whatever matches your layout).

Note that with this formula, the subtotal will be full of zeroes anywhere the cost empty. Change the number format to accounting and it will replace the 0s with dashes. You could also use:

```
=IF($C2>0,SUM($C$2:$C2),"")
```

Which will leave the values of the "empty" D cells as an empty string.